# How to show Unicode in place of "????" in WCF web services

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, unicode

**The Service**

ISayHello.cs (interface)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace MyWCFService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IHelloService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string SayHello(String name, String language);
    }
}
```

**SayHello.cs** (class)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
namespace MyWCFService
{   
    public class HelloService : IHelloService
    {
        public string SayHello(String name, String language)
        {
            switch (language)
            {
                case "en":
                    return "Hello " + name;

                case "ja":
                    return "こんにちは " + name;

                case "ch":
                    return "您好 " + name;

                case "es":
                    return "Hola " + name;

                default:
                    return "Unsupported Language";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Accessing Class**
Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
namespace WCFServiceTester
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your name: ");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your language: ");
            string lang = Console.ReadLine();

            HelloServiceClient hsc = new HelloServiceClient();
            Console.WriteLine(hsc.SayHello(name, lang));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and I'm new with C#. 
When I am running program.cs the output in case I choose language ch(chinese) or ja(japanese) is as follows :

enter your name : 
Bruce
enter your language :
ja

???? Bruce (instead of こんにちは Bruce)

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1481581.aspx?Unicode+characters+becoming+

Comment: `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;`

Answer (score 2):

Your code should support UNICODE just fine. Your Console Font that's printing it, is not. At least not by default. Switch your Console to a UNICODE font.

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode
```